# Is this definition of the verb oxidize correct?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, terminology

UPDATED VERSION:

There are a dozen definitions of the verb oxidize in various dictionaries. My question is whether the definition in the end of this post holds true. I have added the words in bold.

And if we think of oxidation as "electron theft", would the two pairs of three sentences match as to who's getting "robbed"?

Oxygen oxidizes Sodium.
Sodium is oxidized by Oxygen.
Sodium oxidizes (intransitive).

Oliver robs Sophie.
Sophie is robbed by Oliver.
Sophie robs.

"Undergo or cause to undergo a reaction in which electrons are lost to **oxygen or** another species"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the definition is actually quite clear; the problem may be more likely to be solved on [ELL.SE]

Comment: Found this sort of unclear use in French chem slang too. Where the equivalent of oxidize may refer to what has been oxidized or to what indeed oxidizes a reducent species.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn chemistry from a dictionary? Anyway from the language point this is perfectly clear and also chemically correct. When I say "Fred made Joe hit Bill", you also know who is hurt, right? Don't let yourself be confused by the chemical verb. It's still english, not chemlish.

Comment: @Alchimista, exactly! When the dictionary definition says that to "oxidize" is to undergo a reaction where electrons are lost to another species, it doesn't say who's doing the losing. It could very well be oxygen that comes in contact with another species and does the losing.

Comment: @Karl. The dictionary definion left out who's doing what. I was wondering if the definition would still be correct if I inserted the part in bold? If you say "Fred made Joe hit Bill" you've introduced three characters. I wish there were "charcters" in the dictinoary definition.

Comment: @Gelb No it doesn't, please read properly. Definition of *to cut*: split into pieces by use of a knive or scissors. Get my point? You don't need paper or string or carrot to define "to cut". And yes, the other thing, that "looses electrons to oxygen or another species" could also be *another* oxygen. Oxygen oxidises an oxide to peroxide for example.

Comment: @Gelb "I was wondering if the definition would still be correct if I inserted the part in bold?" Why didn't you say so in your original question?

Comment: @Karl. Thanks. Cutting is easy to visualize. Let's say Joe cut Bill in the face; no doubt who's doing what. But if ordinary oxygen and sodium atoms get together and oxidize, by the words it sounds like oxidize belongs to oxygen. Alas, I see "curse of knowledge" made me not emphasize what you quoted in the original question. I see it would've been much clearer that way.

Answer (score 2):

In everyday language "oxidation" is used to describe a reaction with oxygen.

This definition, however, is not scientifically correct.
The more correct definition would be "A reaction in which an atom loses an electron" or "A reaction in which the oxidation state of an atom increases".

This means that in a reaction between hydrogen and chloric gas, which results in HCl (hydrogen chloride) is also an oxidation, because the hydrogen in HCl has a partial positive charge it did not have before, which counts as "losing an electron". This means that **an oxidation does not require oxygen to be involved.**

You might consider looking up how to determine the oxidation state of an atom because it makes deciding if an oxidation takes place easier.

Comment: Thanks, GreenSmurf. So, the definition I suggested was correct. When oxidation occurs then electrons can be lost to oxygen, but they needn't be. So "lost to oxygen or another species" would we correct.